# Pandas / How to insert variable number of lines inside a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

Here is the structure of my dataframe

| plan | ADO_ver_x | ADO_incr_x | ADO_ver_y | ADO_incr_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3ABP3 | 25.0 | 4.0 | 25.0 | 7.0 |

I would like to add `ADO_incr_y - ADO_incr_x` lines, which means in this case the result would be :

| plan | ADO_ver_x | ADO_incr_x | ADO_ver_y | ADO_incr_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3ABP3 | 25.0 | 4.0 | 25.0 | 5.0 |
| 3ABP3 | 25.0 | 5.0 | 25.0 | 6.0 |
| 3ABP3 | 25.0 | 6.0 | 25.0 | 7.0 |

Is there a Panda/Pythonic way to do that ?

I was thinking something like :

```
reps = [ val2-val1 for val2, val1 in zip(df_insert["ADO_incr_y"],df_insert["ADO_incr_x"]) ]
df_insert.loc[np.repeat(df.index_insert.values, reps)]
```

But I don't get the incremental progression :
4 -> 5, 5->-6, 6 -> 7

How can I get the index inside the list comprehension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the data, then modify with `groupby.cumcount()`:

```
repeats = df['ADO_incr_y'].sub(df['ADO_incr_x']).astype(int)
out = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(repeats))

out['ADO_incr_x'] += out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
out['ADO_incr_y'] = out['ADOE_incr_x'] + 1
```